# Неправильная обработка исключений

Tags: python

Скажите, почему следующая программа выводит ошибку? Почему не выводит просто имя ошибки, которое я задал?

```
a = 'ello'
if a != 'hello':
    raise ValueError('ошибка')
else:
    a = a

try:
    print(a)
except ValueError as ve:
    print('ошибка ', ve)
```

Вывод:

```
  File "C:/User/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise ValueError('ошибка')
ValueError: ошибка
```

Comment: Что-то ничего не понятно. Вы в строке 3 выбрасываете ошибку — вот она и отпечаталась. Все остальные строки не работают, и даже `print(a)` тоже не работает, потому что вы прервали работу программы в строке 3 и дальше дело не пошло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может так

```
a = 'ello'
try:
    if a != 'hello':
        raise ValueError('ошибка')
    
except ValueError as ve:
    print('ошибка ', ve)
```